# Python restFUL web service - routing to a specific function in a file

Tags: python, web-services, rest, http, werkzeug

I am implementing a simple API in python using werkzeug. I have created a simple application 'localhost'. I want to execute a function after a GET request. I am confused with URL routing. I have gone through [this](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/routing/) tutorial and implemented routing but still can't figure out how to send a request to another file. Here is my code:

```
url_map = Map([
    Rule('/spell', endpoint='spell_checker.py'),
    Rule('/he', endpoint='hello/test')
])


   @Request.application
    def application(request):
      urls = url_map.bind_to_environ(environ)
      try:
        endpoint, args = urls.match()
        print(endpoint + " " + args)
        #urls.dispatch('test')
      except httplib.HTTPException, e:
        return e(environ, start_response)

       start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
       return ['Rul1e points to %r with arguments %r' % (endpoint, args)]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
        run_simple('127.0.0.1', 4000, application)
```

I have another another in a file named hello.py in the same directory

```
def index():
    print 'This is the test'
```

I want to call index function from URL like localhost:4000/hello which will call the index function of the file hello.py
Kindly assist me.

Comment: could you paste the whole code.

Comment: Have you tried importing the module yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function from an external library first of all you have to import the external library

```
import foo #your library
```

And then for calling a function "foo_function" you have to call this function using:

```
foo.foo_function(args) #where args are declared in the hello.py file
```

Comment: I have another .py file in the same directory and my aim is to write a restFUL webservice. I want to call the function via URL like 'localhost:4000/hello'

Answer (score 0):

> The endpoint is typically a string and can be used to uniquely
>   identify the URL

So it doesn't bind a function to a url, you have to do it yourself.
After this line

```
endpoint, args = urls.match()
```

you can put some kind of control statements to run specific functions, in your case:

```
if endpoint == "hello/test":
    hello.index(request, **args)
```

assuming you have imported `hello` module when you point your browser to `\he` the program will call `hello.index` function.

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/#step-4-the-routing